# How to limit Fortify CPU usage?

Tags: cpu-usage

Is there a way to limit the CPU usage of Fortify Scan? It seems it keeps using 100% of the CPU usage and make the computer fan becomes very loud like it wants to explode. I don't mind longer scan time as long as it does not damage the computer.

Comment: Several ways to do that. One is via Task Manager: right-click on the program in the Processes tab, choose "Go to details", then in Details, right-click again and Set priority to Low, or even Idle, if need be. You can also use two freeware third-parties that'll let you do that (I have installed both on my PC): Process Hacker (here: https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/) and Battleship Encoder Shirasé (here: http://mion.faireal.net/BES/). The former is pretty much a Task Manager on steroids, the second has a steeper learning curve but can fine-tune any program's CPU usage. Up to you.

Comment: I did similar to you, but I set using the affinity instead. It bases on the number of processor core you have.

Comment: That's a good option too. My Lenovo laptop has a Pentium P6100, so I can't be too picky as to which of its two cores I can devote to this task/process or that... :-D As long as you got it working to your satisfaction, I'm a happy camper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by opening Task Manager > Details > Right click on "sourceanalyzer.exe" > Set Affinity > check how many cores you want to use to do Fortify Scan.